# Query WP Page for Buddypress Group Home

Tags: wp-query, buddypress, loop

I've created a new home template for my buddypress groups called front.php. With the code below, I've attempted to display the content of a wp page whose name corresponds to the group name. The loop I have below is in fact displaying pages. But instead of displaying the content of only the corresponding page, it is displaying the content of ALL pages with names that correspond to bp groups. What am I missing?

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'page', /*'pagename' => bp_the_group()*/ ); 
        query_posts( $args ); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="post">

<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <div class="entry">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

<?php edit_post_link( __( '{ Edit }', 'woothemes' ), '<span class="small">', '</span>' ); ?>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't have `WOO Themes` a support forum for stuff like this?

Comment: While I'm on the topic, I'd also like to make the edit_post_link visible only for group managers and admins. Haven't been able to locate a bp_is_group_manager tag.

Comment: Hey Kaiser ... yeah, Woo has great customer service. But this question is a bit outside of their range. I'm using their theme as my base, but I've done all the bp customization myself. This question is something I've seen referenced in other places with no solid answers. Just thought I'd pitch it here for the wide community to take a shot at.

Comment: Ok, thought this is a dedicated BP theme.

Comment: As far as the admin and managers edit link goes, that should be a separate question. The answer, though, is to use the `bp_is_item_mod()` and `bp_is_item_admin()` functions.

Comment: @Joseph, Thanks for tolerating the hijack there and for the answer to part 2.

Comment: Any insight on the loop issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `bp_the_group()`. This function doesn't return a value - it's akin to WP_Query's `the_post()`.

Try:

```
'pagename => bp_get_current_group_slug()
```

Comment: Thanks Boone! Looks like I'll be defaulting to your Docs plugin for now. I'd still like navigation options that look like the plugin pages on the buddypress extensions site. But I suppose that will be a ways off still.